# In Python 3.7/Django 3, how can I get the rendered HTML of a page in a web browser?

Tags: python, html, django, render, python-webbrowser

I'm using Python 3.7 with Django 3.  I currently use the following code for generating a web browser with a given URL

```
filePath = '/tmp/cat_and_dog.webp'
searchUrl = 'http://www.google.hr/searchbyimage/upload'
multipart = {'encoded_image': (filePath, open(filePath, 'rb')), 'image_content': '', }
response = requests.post(searchUrl, files=multipart, allow_redirects=False)
fetchUrl = response.headers['Location']
webbrowser.open(fetchUrl)
```

How do I get the HTMl of the rendered DOM?  Note that this is different than what "view source" reveals.  I'm more interested in getting a version of the DOM that I see when I run "Inspect Element" in my browser.  I may be using improper terminology but hopefully it is clear the actual HTML I wish to extract what the browser renders.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the render_to_string function

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def some_function():

    rendered_template = render_to_string('template_name.html','context')
```

Comment: I'm not connecting the dots.  How do I go from my "webbrowser.open(fetchUrl)" call (or an equivalent call) to what you have?